# Reproduce Google Keep layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, grid

I'm coding a note application inspired by Google Keep.
The text inside the notes is formatted in a rather special way as shown in this image.

[image: Google Keep Layout]

Do you have any idea how I can reproduce this formatting (the "grid" and size of the text that changes according to words and their size?
Here is a picture of my application.

[image: my Layout]

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.